# question mark operator not working with count

Tags: c#

Following is my null operator check

```
if (vessels?.Vessels?.Count == 0)
            { }
```

and object is below

```
private static readonly DataQueueItem _emptyVessel = new DataQueueItem()
    {
        VesselId = 1,
        Vessels = null
    };
```

It is going in else part but it should be in if block.
I am confused why it is happening.
Any help

Comment: If `vessels.Vessels` is `null`, then `vessels.Vessels?.Count` is `null`. `null` is not `0`. so the `if` statement won't be hit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change your code into =>

```
if ((vessels?.Vessels?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
{
// do something.
}
```

**Explanation:** As `vessels` can be null or `vessels.Vessels` can be null so, `vessels?.Vessels?.Count` will return `(int?)` type. At the same time, in the `if` condition `if (vessels?.Vessels?.Count == 0)` in the question, we are trying check a (int?)==(int). Which might not worked as you expected. We can not check `null` to a value. That's why I have added `(vessels?.Vessels?.Count ?? 0)`. That part will return 0 if `vessels?.Vessels?.Count` is null. So, value will be checked with a value.

Comment: An explanation of *why* this change is necessary would be nice

Comment: Ok I will update with an explanation @canton7. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @canton7 I have update and answer with an explanation. Please check and let me know if you think I have missed anything. :-)

Comment: "*we are trying check a (int?)==(int). Which is an error for C#.*" -- that's incorrect, it's absolutely legal to do that in C#.

Comment: Thank @canton7. I have changed it . :)

Comment: The key point I think is that `vessels?.Vessels?.Count` will be `null` if `vessels.Vessels` is `null`, and `null` is not equal to `0`, so the `if (vessels?.Vessels?.Count == 0)` will fail

Comment: With c#9 patterns you could do `if (vessel?.Vessels is (null or { Count: 0 })` or other similar constructs like `if(vessel?.Vessels?.Count is (null or 0))`

Comment: I usually do something like `(vessels?.Vessels?.Count > 0) != true` which I feel shows the semantic better. But it's personal preference

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
if (vessels.Vessels == null)
{
    // Code
}
```

The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one that does not refer to any object. null **is not the same** as 0.